# Loading multiple tables from multiple files in s3 using snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, load

I am trying to load data from files in S3 location to tables in snowflake using copy command.
But the issue is that I have multiple tables in snowflake which needs to be loaded by different files in S3. Instead of writing copy command for each table, is there a way to load multiple tables of snowflake at once?

Comment: The COPY INTO <table> command works only for one table. If you want to insert into multiple tables you probably need to use a programmatic way by writing either a stored procedure or maybe a client side script (in Python or any other language).

Comment: Any sample Stored procedure that you have where in we have the details of the files in S3 and the table names in a file and then passing the contents of this file as input to copy command?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a code writing service so you would need to attempt to write the SP yourself and then ask for help if you get stuck. It should be reasonably straightforward as you would pass in the files/tables as parameters (probably in arrays as there would an unknown number of values); in the SP you'd have a parameterised version of the COPY into command and then you'd loop through the input arrays, passing the values into the COPY INTO command and executing it

Comment: I tried writing the below code, but I get stuck at the line where I write the copy command.

Comment: create or replace procedure SP_SQL_RunBatchSQL()
returns varchar
language sql
as
$$
declare
  c1 cursor for select lake_table, file from customer_db.public.s3_to_lake;
  sql text;
  sql_template text; 
begin
  sql_template = $$ copy into ${TABLE_NAME} FROM @customer_db.public.lake_load_stage/${READ_FILE}$$;
  for record in c1 do
    sql := replace(replace(sql_template, 'TABLE_NAME', record.lake_table), 'READ_FILE', record.file);
    execute immediate sql; 
  end for;
end;
$$;